# Sorting specific structure objects by their properties

Tags: javascript, sorting, object

So I have such dummy data object:

```
var Products = {
    'sku': {n:'Trampolines rain covers',v:'7Ft',l:'http://www.google.com',i:['media/cache/search/media/1151-Trampoline-jumping-mat.png','media/cache/searchSuggest/media/1151-Trampoline-jumping-mat.png','#'],r:['4','3.2','0','1','3','0','0'],p:['7.99','9.99'],d:'Some kind of description',f:'Features',b:'Benefits',s:'Specifications'},
    'sku2': {n:'Icon cast adjustable dumbbell',v:'10kg',l:'http://www.google.com',i:['media/cache/search/media/1167-Single-dumbbell.png','media/cache/searchSuggest/media/1167-Single-dumbbell.png','#'],r:['4','2.5','1','0','1','0','2'],p:['7.99','9.99'],d:'Some kind of description',f:'Features',b:'Benefits',s:'Specifications'},
    'sku3': {n:'Trampolines safety net & bases',v:'6Ft',l:'http://www.google.com',i:['media/cache/search/media/1195-Trampoline-safety-net.png','media/cache/searchSuggest/media/1195-Trampoline-safety-net.png','#'],r:['3','3.5','1','0','1','0','1'],p:['7.99','9.99'],d:'Some kind of description',f:'Features',b:'Benefits',s:'Specifications'},
    'sku4': {n:'Andico spring for trampolines',v:'5.5 inch',l:'http://www.google.com',i:['media/cache/search/media/1166-Trampoline.png','media/cache/searchSuggest/media/1166-Trampoline.png','#'],r:['3','3.5','1','0','1','0','1'],p:['7.99','9.99'],d:'Some kind of description',f:'Features',b:'Benefits',s:'Specifications'}
}
```

and then I have array of skus

```
var skus = ['sku','sku3','sku4'];
```

My task is to sort this array by sku object property **n** (which is string / product title of multi words) alphabetically ascending.

I know for that I should use .sort(ref) function, but I wonder with function inside, something like:

```
skus.sort(function(a,b) { });
```

But I can't find out how to formulate the inner function to make the job done. Maybe I should do this in another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're very nearly there. Within the function, you use `a` and `b` to look up the entries on your `Products` object, so you can compare entries:

```
skus.sort(function(a, b) {
    var an = Products[a].n,
        bn = Products[b].n;
    if (an === bn) {
        return 0;
    }
    return an < bn ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, works smoothly. I have couple questions: does sorting automatically recognize aplha or numeric values? I tried changing **Products[a].n** & ...b].n to **Products[a].p[1]** ..b].p[1] but it sorts not correctly. :/ P.s. I did set different p[1] values, should it use different function in such case?

Comment: @Tautvydas: All of your `p[1]` values are `'9.99'`, so they're all equal. Any order is a valid order sorted by your `p[1]` values.

Comment: Yes thank you, I had changed them to different, but then I realized that those values are strings... Thank you T.J. !